# ParserError: Expected token Comma got 'SubEther'

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am having trouble with this parse error when I compile the abi.  I want to be able to add the argument that gets passed into the function to the workdone. However when I try to do that I get a parse error. If I hardcode in a number then it compiles without issue.  Any help?

doesn't compile

```
function test1(address addr1, uint8 num) nonReentrant external {
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       //do the thing
    }        
    workDone[msg.sender] = workDone[msg.sender].add(uint256(num ether));
}
```

compiles fine

```
function test1(address addr1) nonReentrant external {
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       //do the thing
    }        
    workDone[msg.sender] = workDone[msg.sender].add(uint256(10 ether));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that units like `ether` can only be used with integer literals at compile time. Just multiply by 10^18 instead:

```
workDone[msg.sender].add(num * 10**18);
```